Time Series Prediction with Hidden Variables
I have time series data sampled every 10 seconds. I want to predict a target variable  for 5 steps ahead using the input variable at the current time along with 10 past lags. My problem is that there is an unobserved hidden variable affecting the target variable . How can I infer this hidden unobserved variable and improve my predictions?
I want to use Python for coding.
I used theano and arviz. But I'm not sure about the correct methodology.
